On-screen/virtual keyboard on Kubuntu 24.04 with X11
there are various posts about touchscreens and on-screen/virtual keyboard usage for (K)Ubuntu on X11, but most seem to be rather dated and don't really help me. I'm looking for a simple on-screen keyboard that stays on top and either appears automatically when an input box is focused or is available using a taskbar icon. I don't need any fancy features like gestures/swiping, word completion, etc., just a plain keyboard giving access to the letter, number and symbol keys. Function keys and a full set of modifier keys would be nice, but may not be absolutely necessary.
So far I've tried those options without success:

onboard: Crashes with a segfault whenever the window gets focus
matchbox-keyboard: Trouble displaying key symbols (ENTER is rendered as a box), only letter keys and space, no other keys; apparently no support for minimize to toolbar icon
xvkbd: Sort of working, but renders badly and behaves buggy, like randomly entering characters and putting a word completion box over the top row of buttons (including backspace); apparently no support for minimize to toolbar icon
corekeyboard: Requires Flatpak to install (the package links on their GitLab page seem to be invalid); is displayed over the task bar and apparently displays no task bar icon -> once it is hidden, there is no way to get to it again without restarting its process
maliit-keyboard: Appears to work with Wayland, but I haven't been able to reliably display it under X11; this is probably the most promising, but I haven't yet found out what I need to configure so that it really shows up either by focusing an input field or using some kind of task bar icon

Interestingly, the login and also lock screens provide a "Virtual keyboard" button in the bottom left, which brings up a keyboard that works and looks just fine. But so far I wasn't able to start this same keyboard while logged in. I don't know if that is just a feature of SDDM, but I actually thought that only the login screen is run by SDDM and not the lock screen.
Now I suppose that it would be possible to create something workable with xvkbd or maybe matchbox-keyboard with some tinkering. But I can't really believe that there is no virtual keyboard around for KDE/Plasma that just works, as touchscreen devices are now basically everywhere.
Am I just missing something? Thanks for any pointers!

I had to put onboard  in a venv to get it running.

What was the error message for onboard?

@ArchismanPanigrahi There is no error message except "Segmentation fault". dmesg also just shows "segfault at 10 ip ... sp ... error 4 in python3.12[...] likely on CPU 11. I wonder if it is just not compatible with Python 3.12.

@JayCravens How did you do this? I just installed onboard using apt and I don't see it available as a pip package. I guess I could download it from GitHub and try to run it in a venv and so on, but given that it appears to be completely unmaintained (the current version 1.4.1 is from 2017), this seems to be asking for more trouble in the future.

@PhilippBurch Yes, it's certainly not optimal.  I have been having this issue off and on with onboard.  With the current venv, it will run, but to open settings, it doesn't work from the app itself.  I have to run onboard-settings from the app directory.  Problem is, there is no alternative that's worth using, not that I've found.  The command is pip install onboard.client to install with pip.

onboard.client appears to be some data handling toolkit, not an on-screen keyboard. Are we talking about the same thing?

xvkbd has a cli mode

Not that much of an answer, but at least some progress that might help others on the same route:
maliit-keyboard
I got the keyboard to show under X11 as follows:

Install maliit-keyboard
Run im-config
Confirm that you want to change settings and then choose the user configuration activate Mallit input method framework
NOTE: Don't log out/reboot now, as login will fail with a black screen (at least for me with KDE Plasma) when maliit is not running at the time of login
$ sudo nano /etc/X11/Xsession.d/10maliit-keyboard and populate the new file with this content:

maliit-keyboard &
export QT_IM_MODULE=maliit
export GTK_IM_MODULE=maliit
export CLUTTER_IM_MODULE=maliit
export SDL_IM_MODULE=maliit


Save the file, log out (or reboot) and log in again.

This should now display the Maliit keyboard whenever a text field is focused. This is good. But there are several drawbacks:

Starting maliit-keyboard from the Xsession config file and sending it to the background feels extremely hacky.

The keyboard shows up whenever a text field is focused, also if this is done using a mouse. It can be hidden by swiping down on it, but this will just show it again as soon as another text input field is focused. Given that it is huge on a decent-sized screen, this makes using the computer with a mouse again very annoying.

The keyboard just displays over any active window, so you may constantly need to move them around to reach all required fields.

The keyboard itself can't be moved or resized.

There is no way to temporarily turn the keyboard off.


It might be a viable solution for a computer that is only used with touch input, but rather not as an alternative option for a machine which is also used with a real keyboard and mouse.
onboard
I've just found a bug report about onboard crashing. dr.n apparently found a way to get it working:

Run $ onboard-settings
Go to Keyboard -> Advanced
Change Input Options -> Touch Input from Xinput to GTK
Close the settings window and start onboard normally

It is old and unmaintained software, but so far it looks to be the best option available for me. I haven't extensively used/tested it yet and will likely need to change some settings, but lacking a better alternative, I'll probably stick with it for now.

qtvkbd: autostarts hidden in tray, nice full keyboard.
kvkbd: similar to qtvkbd, but pops up on login.
Both compiled quickly and nicely on my Kubuntu laptops.
Here are my Intel x86_64 binaries.

Thanks, good to know. I've found references to kvkbd before, but now way to actually install it. I didn't try to build it from source, though. For now, onboard seems to fulfill my needs; if that changes, I'll probably give those a try as well.

@PhilippBurch Here are my Intel x86_64 binaries that I made. Just copy to your system directories as shown. kvkbd is a standalone binary, so I keep it in my home bin directory.
